# How to concat subquery elements

Tags: mysql

I have a database table which have a field 'profile_id' which contains profile ids concatenated with a separator comma. I know that this is a rude solution, but cannot change it, because the system uses this database for ages (before I joined the development), and it would be a hughe task to redesign the database. So I need a query where I can get the short profile identifications glued together instead of the profile_ids.
Here is an example to make it clear:

```
SELECT 
    production_stages.id,
    production_stages.`name`, 
    production_stages.production_stage_group_id,
    production_stages.profile_id,
    production_stages.is_terminal,
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finished_production_serial_stages WHERE stage_id = production_stages.id) = 0, 0, 1) AS 'in_use'
FROM production_stages WHERE production_stage_group_id = 11
```

This query will return something like this: [image: result table]

I tried to select and concatenate the corresponding profile short names but I only get the first one. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    production_stages.id,
    production_stages.`name`,
    production_stages.production_stage_group_id,
    (SELECT CONCAT(short_name) FROM `profile` WHERE profileid IN(production_stages.profile_id)) AS 'profiles',
    production_stages.profile_id,
    production_stages.is_terminal,
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finished_production_serial_stages WHERE stage_id = production_stages.id) = 0, 0, 1) AS 'in_use'
FROM production_stages WHERE production_stage_group_id = 11
```

As you can see in the result, the profiles column contains only one of the profile short names:
[image]

I'd like to get something like ADM,AGV,AGM,BESZLA in the profile column. Of course in the profile table, the profile_ids are referring to the short_name of the profile e.g.:
1->ADM, 13->AGV, 12->AGM, 19->BESZLA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are trying with `IN()` clause will not work for comma separated values stored in column you need to use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT 
    ps.id,
    ps.`name`,
    ps.production_stage_group_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.short_name) AS `profiles`,
    ps.profile_id,
    ps.is_terminal,
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finished_production_serial_stages WHERE stage_id = ps.id) = 0, 0, 1) AS 'in_use'
FROM production_stages ps
JOIN `profile` p ON(FIND_IN_SET(p.profileid,ps.profile_id) > 0)
WHERE ps.production_stage_group_id = 11
GROUP BY ps.id
```

> Note for using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by
>   the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet

Comment: Just a little modification: If I use the FIND_IN_SET with the JOIN, the production_stages whith null in the profile_id will lost, so I relocated the FIND_IN_SET expression to the subselect query, and now it works perfectly Thank you!

Comment: So the sql now: 

`SELECT 
 production_stages.id,
 production_stages.name,
 production_stages.production_stage_group_id,
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(short_name) FROM profile WHERE FIND_IN_SET(profile.profileid ,production_stages.profile_id)) AS 'profiles',
 production_stages.profile_id,
 production_stages.is_terminal,
 IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM finished_production_serial_stages WHERE stage_id = production_stages.id) = 0, 0, 1) AS 'in_use'
FROM production_stages WHERE production_stages.production_stage_group_id = 11`